# Could i add layout configuration in application.ini during run time in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

We are using Zend framework. We are creating module from Admin Panel or during Run time, but its layout is not working because we need to define following code in the application.ini

```
pizzahut.resources.layout.layout = "layout"
pizzahut.resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/pizzahut/layouts/scripts/"
```

Is this possible that we can edit our application.ini during run time using PHP,
or could we add new layout configuration in application.ini using PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some googling, I have found that we can edit our `application.ini` with PHP.

Here is the code:

```
$config = parse_ini_file(
    APPLICATION_PATH . "/configs/application.ini", 
    TRUE, 
    INI_SCANNER_RAW
);

$config["production"]["$store.resources.layout.layout"] = "layout";

$layoutPath = 'APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/' . $store . '/layouts/scripts/"';
$config["production"]["$store.resources.layout.layoutPath"] = $layoutPath;

$result = Helper_common::write_ini_file(
    $config,
    APPLICATION_PATH . "/configs/application.ini", 
    TRUE
);
```

Here `parse_ini_file` is used to retrieve content from the `application.ini` file **with constants**.

`write_ini_file` is the function that I am calling to rewrite the `application.ini` file.

Here is the `write_ini_file` function:

```
public static function write_ini_file($assoc_arr, $path, $has_sections=FALSE) { 
    $content = ""; 
    if ($has_sections) { 
        foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
            $content .= "[".$key."]\n"; 
            foreach ($elem as $key2=>$elem2) { 
                if(is_array($elem2)) 
                { 
                    for($i=0;$i<count($elem2);$i++) 
                    { 
                        $content .= $key2."[] = ".$elem2[$i]."\n"; 
                    } 
                } 
                else if($elem2=="") $content .= $key2." = \n"; 
                else $content .= $key2." = ".$elem2."\n"; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    else { 
        foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
            if(is_array($elem)) 
            { 
                for($i=0;$i<count($elem);$i++) 
                { 
                    $content .= $key2."[] = ".$elem[$i]."\n"; 
                } 
            } 
            else if($elem=="") $content .= $key2." = \n"; 
            else $content .= $key2." = ".$elem."\n"; 
        } 
    } 

    if (!$handle = fopen($path, 'w')) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    if (!fwrite($handle, $content)) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    fclose($handle); 
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ini files are loaded when the application starts running, before bootstrap , so no you can't.

check these out to see how to change layout dynamically at run-time:

http://vandenbos.org/zend-framework-module-specific-layout/

[Change Layout in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792560/change-layout-in-bootstrap)

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=2466&start=0

[Setting up Zend Layout from Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977226/setting-up-zend-layout-from-bootstrap)

[setting layout file for module inside bootstrap in zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390948/setting-layout-file-for-module-inside-bootstrap-in-zend)